# How to debug angular when there is no exception in console

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angular and wanted to use some modules. I have used a  angular module and made it to work on a html page by itself. But When I merged this module into my main html it stopped working. Say for example ng-click is not working. Since this is a third party module and since it did not throw any exception in the console of chrome developer tools I cannot figure out what is the exception or what is causing it not to work

Please advise..

I know this question is generic but if in such scenarios what is the best way to solve the problem

Thanks

Comment: Use chrome plugin Batarang https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

Comment: even when there is no exception in console will that help

Comment: so, you can check all scope variable and whatever value they hold. that will help you to identify if your scope has value or not. that ways you can actually know what block of your code is breaking.